# How to delete all text before and when string occurs on sed

Tags: bash, sed

I remembered how to do this and even learned it from Stack Exchange, but forgot how I googled it so now I can't find it. The answers I am finding now are not what I'm looking for. Here is an example text:

```
The quick
brown fox
jumps over
the lazy
dog
```

I want sed to remove everything before and when it says "jum" so the output would be something like this:

```
ps over
the lazy
dog
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What if there are more than one `jum` in the file? Should we keep the first? The last?

Comment: @terdon That would be too bad, in that case I would delete more than just the "jum".

Comment: But how do you want to handle cases with more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`, and assuming your file is small enough to fit in memory, you can do this:

```
$ sed -z 's/.*jum//' file 
ps over
the lazy
dog
```

The `-z` tells `sed` to treat its input as NUL-separated, meaning that it expects a NUL (`\0`) to signidfy the end of each line. Since your file will have no NUL characters, this has the effect of sed treating the entire file as a single line so we can do the whole thing in a single `s///` operation.

Note that this will find the *last* `jum` in the file and delete everything before that. If there are other occurrences of `jum` earlier, those will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ne '1,/^jum/{s/^jum//p;d;}' -e p
```

As @Sundeep states in comment, if you have GNU sed, use preferably
`sed -ne '0,/^jum/{s/^jum//p;d;}' -e p`. This would work even if `jum` on the first line. which is not the case with `1,/^jum/`.

Here is what it does:

- `sed -n`: don't print anything unless told to
- `1,/^jum/`: for lines between the 1st one and the one that starts with `jum` inclusive:

  - `s/^jum//p`: if you can remove "jum" at start of line, print the result
  - `d`: and proceed with next line
- `-e p`: all other lines, just print them.

Comment: Won't work if the first line starts with `jum`. With `GNU sed`, you can use `0,/pattern/` to match the first line as well. Also, you can use `s///p` to avoid repeating the pattern.

Comment: @Sundeep you're right twice. I'll edit the answer. I just tend not to use s///. sed script are cryptic enough without this additional magic. I like your awk answer and was tempted to use awk too (although I probably would not have written a solution as clever and clear as yours), but OP asked for sed. Anyway, you're a master at both. _Chapeau_ !

Comment: Why are we assuming that `jump` will be the first word of a line?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```bash
$ awk 'sub(/^jum/, ""){f=1} f' ip.txt
ps over
the lazy
dog
```

If the substitution succeeds, set a flag to print the lines.

Comment: Why are we assuming that jump will be the first word of a line?

Comment: Hmm, good point. Perhaps the OP can clarify, along with multiple match case.